# Consider three subsets $A, B, C$ of $U$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Consider three subsets $A, B, C$ of $U$. Observe that they do form an ordered triple $(A, B, C)$. From this ordered triple, we can form the intersection $A \cap B \cap C$ in two ways: $(A \cap B) \cap C$ and $A \cap (B \cap C)$. Prove that it is possible to define a function $$g : \mathcal{P}(U) × \mathcal{P}(U) × \mathcal{P}(U) → \mathcal{P}(U), (A, B, C) \mapsto A \cap B \cap C$$ regardless of the way we place the brackets.

Comment: Okay, I did that.  It was fun.  Now you do it.  (In other words show your thoughts.  Or explain what you don't understand.)  Basically all the want you to do is prove that $(A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap (B \cap C)$ so the function $g(A,B,C) = A \cap B \cap C = (A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap (B \cap C)$ is well-defined.

Comment: I will admit, putting the question in terms of functions and power sets is very obfiscating.  But basically we can always define a function $g(A,B,C) = operation on A B and C$ no matter what type of things A,B, and C are so long as $operation on A B and C$ is well-defined and not ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that, for any three sets $A,B,C$, we have $(A\cap B)\cap C=A\cap (B\cap C)$. To show this, note that
$$\begin{align} &x\in A\cap(B\cap C)\\
\iff  &x\in A\,\land\, x\in B\cap C \\
\iff &x\in A\,\land\, (x\in B\,\land\, x\in C)\\
\iff &(x\in A\,\land\, x\in B)\,\land\, x\in C\\
\iff &x\in A\cap B\,\land x\in C\\
\iff &x\in (A\cap B)\cap C \end{align}$$